# Ho to force the pyright language server to use a interpreter on a mounted volume

Tags: neovim, filetype-python, lsp

I have a problem with the following setup:

- the volume of a remote machine is mounted using sshfs
- nvim is opened on the mounted volume to ensure all my plugins and settings work
- ~/anaconda3/envs/.. is interpreter path on the mounted volume I want to use

Unfortunately I can't get pyright to use the interpreter on the remote volume.

So far I tried:

```lua
return {
  settings = {
    python = {
      pythonPath = "~/anaconda3/envs/env/bin/python3"
    }
  }
}
```

setting `venvPath` and `venv` in the `pyright` language server config

```lua
return {
  settings = {
    python = {
      venvPath = "~/anaconda3/envs",
      venv = "clthesis"
    }
  }
}
```

configuring the global python host to

```lua
   vim.g.python_host_prog = "~/anaconda3/envs/env/bin/python"
   vim.g.python3_host_prog = "~/anaconda3/envs/env/bin/python3"
```

I know it's a finicky setup so any help appreciated

Comment: Third paragraph [here](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/configuration.md) says shell variables are not supported, including `~`. Try specifying the absolute path or have lua expand it for you.

Comment: Changed it to `/home/<user>/anaconda3/envs/<env>/bin/python3` in both the pyright config and the `host_prog`'s but unfortunately it still does not work.
`:checkhealth` shows
```
## Python 3 provider (optional)
  - INFO: Using: g:python3_host_prog = "/home/<user>/anaconda3/envs/<env>/bin/python3"
  - WARNING: No Python executable found that can `import neovim`. Using the first available executable for diagnostics.
  - INFO: Executable: Not found
```

Comment: Doesn't `g:python3_host_prog` point to the interpreter you expect? Did you install neovim for that interpreter? Besides, it's pyright you're configuring, not neovim itself, so unless pyright integrates with `:checkhealth` (which I don't recall it does, but I may be mistaken), I wouldn't expect to be able to use `checkhealth` to see if pyright picked up the correct config.

Comment: I assume `g:python3_host_prog` would do what I need. I also `pip install neovim` into the conda environment I want to use and the host_prog points to the correct interpreter. pyright is still not finding my package imports etc.

Comment: That's not what it's used for. Check `:h provider` or simply press `K` while the cursor is over `g:python3_host_prog` to see the documentation. It's used for python plugins, whereas pyright is a standalone language server that the built-in LSP client in nvim is communicating with.

Comment: I do understand that. I just thought that maybe the LSP uses the same path as specified there. Unfortunately it does not and I still did not get it to work. But thank you for your help!